# Perl chdir error

Tags: perl, unix, chdir

I am trying to change the working directory (for configure a WebShpere MQ Queue manager) using Perl in UNIX.

I have to go to the directory `/var/mqm/qmgrs/Q\!MAN` and I have used following code snippet:

```
$QueueManagerPathName = 'Q\!MAN';
chdir('/var/mqm/qmgrs/'.$QueueManagerPathName) or die "Cannot change to dir : /var/mqm/qmgrs/".$QueueManagerPathName."\n";
```

But it does not change the directory and dies giving

```
Cannot change to dir : /var/mqm/qmgrs/Q\!MAN
```

When i remove the variable `$QueueManagerPathName` its working fine and it concludes me that it would be error using `"\!"` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape `!` in the directory name. This should work:

```
my $dir = '/var/mqm/qmgrs/Q!MAN';
chdir $dir or die "Can't cd to $dir: $!\n";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I misunderstood it with the UNIX shell representation. With the usage of `$QueueManagerPathName = 'Q!MAN';` it worked fine. Thank You again

Comment: If you were passing the string to the shell (eg using 'system' or backticks) you would need this, but 'chdir' is native in Perl.

Comment: @Colin: `system("ls !test/*")` and `print \`ls !test/*\`` work as well

Comment: Oh, do they? I thought the shell would interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

Single quoted strings do not interpolate backslash, so you're trying to change to a directory called /var/mqm/qmgrs/Q\!MAN

Either omit the backslash, or use a double-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

You have a backslash in your variable... I'd say that you are doing to much escaping.